# Creating a new column or row in flowgorithm

Tags: multiplication, pseudocode, flowgorithm

I am trying to create a multiplication table from 1 to 10, but print each line one at a time. I need to know how to do this in flowgorithm. I have the chart correct to print the multiplication table but I need to separate it into columns when the loop starts again.

example

```
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
5 10
6 12
7 14
8 16
9 18
10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to draw a matrix/table of numbers, loop on rows and columns:
[image: algorithm]

The output is:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

The XML version:

```xml
    <function name="Main" type="None" variable="">
        <parameters/>
        <body>
            <declare name="r, c, i" type="Integer" array="False" size=""/>
            <for variable="r" start="1" end="10" direction="inc" step="1">
                <for variable="c" start="1" end="10" direction="inc" step="1">
                    <for variable="i" start="Len(ToString(r*c))" end="3" direction="inc" step="1">
                        <output expression="&quot; &quot;" newline="False"/>
                    </for>
                    <output expression="r*c" newline="False"/>
                </for>
                <output expression="&quot;&quot;" newline="True"/>
            </for>
        </body>
    </function>
```